# Will changing a Linux server timezone cause issues?

Tags: ubuntu, timezone

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server running on a cloud instance hosted in another time zone.

Will changing the timezone using the below, cause issues with programs running on the server?

    `$ echo "Australia/Adelaide" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
    $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata`

Instructions taken from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime).

The reason for doing this is so the system time and logs appear correct to the time zone of the development team.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to affect cron jobs as they by default use the system wide time zone (see this [Timezone issue with cron](https://superuser.com/questions/374906/timezone-issue-with-cron).

Many programs which print timestamps will do it in the timezone you set too, and so forth.

But I don't understand what timezone changes time with +/- 30 min? Are you actually meaning that you are going to change actual system time on the VM instance? Because that will cause a wide array of problems (that is if clock is not correct), including, but not limited to, SSL.

Comment: There are some odd time zones with 30/45 min offsets: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html

Comment: that's cool! every day you learn something new.

Comment: The Problem with Time & Timezones - Computerphile: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: I've updated the question.